# Unexpected System.InvalidOperationException: The Visible property cannot be set on Web Part

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to find the cause of the problem described in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212314/sharepoint-sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-the-message-re) where controls on UpdatePanels are not functioning properly. Strangely, this is only happening on intranet clients outside of the main location.

I installed FireBug on a client in the US and clicked on a control. Normally, I would expect a partial update but the response is an error page.

Error 
    An unexpected error has occurred.

```
Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: f73a5a93-46c8-40c9-848e-d00395d927ce 

Date and Time: 27/02/2012 15:43:22
```

Looking in the logs for the CorrelationID, I found

```
Unexpected  System.InvalidOperationException: The Visible property cannot be set on Web Part 'g_da16f6e5_a10a_412c_b051_98e67718af81'.  
It can only be set on a standalone Web Part.
    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  f73a5a93-46c8-40c9-848e-d00395d927ce
```

Has anyone had this kind of problem before?

What could be causing this (bearing in mind that, in-house, this kind of partial update works fine) ?

**SOLUTION**

I was so fixed on why the one one webpart was not working that I did not consider other webparts. There is another webpart which did actually use Visible and this was the cause. It was setting the Visible attribute false when the user is not on the main site. Simple really but cost me a lot of time :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using .Hidden instead of .Visible

I had a similar problem and this is what fixed it for me...

Comment: Thanks. I can't think where I might have used Visible :-/! Any explanation as to why it works in-house but not remotely?